# Dell R720 and Cisco 2960S SFP+ connection

Tags: cisco, sfp, dell

Can I connect a Dell R720 with a Broadcom 57840S Quad Port 10Gb SFP+ Direct Attach Rack Network Daughter Card (540-BBCN) and Cisco 2960S SPF connection?  I'm using a Cisco Twinax cable and the ports show up as cable diconnected.

Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: Which 2960S?  Some 2960S series switches do have SFP+ ports, others only have SFP.  If it only has SFP ports, then the likely answer is no.

Comment: Hello YLearn The model is WS-C2960S-48-FPS-L V02

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

SFP+ = 10gig
SFP = 1gig

Most SFP+ ports will accept an SFP transceiver
SFP ports cannot support SFP+ transceivers

You might be able to connect a 1gig link from the Broadcom to your switch (if the Broadcom supports SFP, which I couldn't find), but you cannot connect a 10gig link to your switch since your four transceiver ports are all SFP, not SFP+.

Answer (score 3):

The Cisco WS-C2960S-48-FPS-L has 4 SFP ports which operate at 1Gbps.

From the documentation I can find on the Broadcom 57840S, it has four SFP+ ports that operate at 10Gbps.  I find no mention that it can support lower data rates.

As for your Cisco Twinax cables, the only ones I am aware of are 10G.  These will not work in your 2960S.  A couple of posts that may be somewhat relevant to this from the Cisco forums would be [here](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11905936/can-sfp-copper-twinax-connection-be-configured-1gb) and [here](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11648126/possible-downgrade-10gb-twinax-cu-sfp-cable-1gb)